Process started by Azure DevOps interactive environment agent ends when pipeline-job finishes
I want to deploy a long-running C#-executable to a Windows Server 2019 machine using Azure DevOps pipelines. The executable needs to run elevated and call an external application that cannot run in session 0. Thus the executable needs to run in an UI-session itself. I therefore use an interactive agent. Unfortunately the executable always closes whenever the pipeline-job finishes, but I need it to keep running.
The behaviour is reproducible using the following pipeline.
jobs:
- deployment: 
  environment: MyEnvironment.MyInteractiveAgent
  strategy:
    runOnce:
      deploy:
        steps:
        - powershell: Start-Process -Verb RunAs C:\Windows\notepad.exe

When I execute Start-Process -Verb RunAs C:\Windows\notepad.exe from PowerShell-window myself on the target machine as the pipeline-user, I can close the PowerShell-window and notepad remains open.
Regardless of whether me or the pipeline-agent starts notepad, it seems to be a child-process of the PowerShell starting it according to the following script (needs PowerShell Core).
$process = Get-Process notepad;

while ($process) {
    Write-Host "$($process.Id) - $($process.Name)";
    $process = $process.Parent;
}

# Starting myself      Starting from agent
# -------------------------------------------
# 9812 - notepad       3940  - notepad
# 3480 - powershell    1676  - powershell
# 5004 - explorer      11388 - powershell
#                      1720  - Agent.Worker
#                      15748 - Agent.Listener
#                      14708 - cmd


The reason was that the interactive agent accidentally ran elevated. When I restarted it non-elevated, the executable kept running after the pipeline-job finished.
To check whether a process runs elevated, I either use the Elevated-column of the Task Manager or this PowerShell-script.
I don't understand why elevation of the agent has this side-effect, but my problem is solved for now.

It seems to be related to the User Account Control (UAC) feature in Windows. When the agent is run with elevated privileges, any processes it spawns will also run with those same elevated privileges. These child processes are tied to the parent process (the agent). When the pipeline job finishes and the agent process ends, it also ends any child processes it started. When you restart the agent without elevation, the child processes are not tied to the lifecycle of the elevated agent process and can keep running.

Can you be more specific about what you mean by tied? Because when I start PowerShell elevated directly and call notepad elevated from there I can close PowerShell and notepad keeps running. And in both cases both processes run in the same user-session and the notepad-process is a child of the PowerShell-process. So that tie seems to exist only for the agent.

The above is just my guess. You can try turning off UAC on Windows and let the agent ran elevated again. Then check if there is the same issue or not.
